# How to collect all distinct values of column2 in each group grouped by column1?

Tags: sql, select, group-by, distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT property1, property2, SUM(property3) FROM t GROUP BY property1;
```

This gives

```
p11 p211 sum(p311, p312, ...)
p12 p221 sum(p321, p322, ...)
```

But I want

```
p11 (p211, p212, ...) sum(p311, p312, ...)
p12 (p221, p222, ...) sum(p321, p322, ...)
```

or something contains the equivalent information.  How to do that?

Comment: Can you do this in Oracle too?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL provides a `GROUP_CONCAT` function that does exactly what you want:

```
SELECT property1, GROUP_CONCAT(property2), SUM(property3) FROM t GROUP BY property1;
```

I don't know what the equivalent is in other RDBMS's.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` seems to truncate at certain point, i.e. if there are more than certain number of rows in the group, and/or the length of the resultant column value passes some threshold, the rest is dropped.  Any idea about that?

Comment: From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat): "The syntax to change the value of group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an unsigned integer:"

`SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;`